# I am selecting CanDeactivate option even though created CanActivate guard in angular CLI

Tags: angular-cli, angular-guards

I am trying to create CanDeactivate guard by using angular CLI but it is creating CanActivate guard even though choosed correct option.

Comment: At least show the command that you are running. [edit] the post and add the command above.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes. Issue has been resolved..Thnks